# runtime failure class wrapping C object

Tags: c++, node.js, native

I am working on updating [node-mapserver](https://github.com/pagameba/node-mapserver) that wraps the [mapserver](http://www.mapserver.org) library in the [class-refactor](https://github.com/pagameba/node-mapserver/tree/class-refactor) branch to a more maintainable code structure (basing my changes on the organization of [node-ogr](https://github.com/zhm/node-ogr/)).

Up to now, I have refactored the main module interface and started on the first class to be wrapped, a mapserver C struct called `errorObj` that I am wrapping with `class MSError`.  The extension builds but I am facing is a runtime assertion error in the extension the first time I trigger a new MSError object to wrap an errorObj.

```
Fatal error in ../deps/v8/src/api.h, line 297
CHECK(allow_empty_handle || that != __null) failed
```

With node 0.10 there is an extremely lengthy stack trace after this which can be seen in [travis build 27.2](https://travis-ci.org/pagameba/node-mapserver/jobs/8745024).  I couldn't find anything particularly useful in the stack trace.

The extension builds and some tests pass (symbols and methods exported from the library itself), but fails when the library tries to create an Object that wraps a C object.

In javascript, I call `mapserver.getError()`.  In the extension, this invokes a mapserver method `errorObj* err = msGetErrorObj();`and returned with `return scope.Close(MSError::New(err));`.  The `New` method of MSError does this:

```
Handle<Value> MSError::New(errorObj *err) {
  HandleScope scope;
  MSError *wrapped = new MSError(err);
  Handle<Value> ext = External::New(wrapped);
  Handle<Object> obj = MSError::constructor->GetFunction()->NewInstance(1, &ext);
  return scope.Close(obj);
}
```

I have attempted to debug this using gdb, the best I can get out of it with my limited skills is that the error happens at this call:

```
  Handle<Object> obj = MSError::constructor->GetFunction()->NewInstance(1, &ext);
```

What I can gather from this is that `ext` is null which means that the `External::New(wrapped)` call is not returning a valid value.  I have confirmed that `errorObj* err` does point to a valid, properly initialized, errorObj structure.  To clarify, there is no actual error, mapserver always returns a valid errorObj but with a code of 0 if there is no error at this time.

Here is, hopefully, the relevant code.

ms_error.hpp

```
#ifndef __NODE_MS_ERROR_H__
#define __NODE_MS_ERROR_H__

#include <v8.h>

#include <node.h>
#include <node_object_wrap.h>

#include <mapserver.h>

using namespace v8;
using namespace node;

class MSError: public node::ObjectWrap {
  public:
    static Persistent<FunctionTemplate> constructor;
    static void Initialize(Handle<Object> target);
    static Handle<Value> New(const Arguments &args);
    static Handle<Value> New(errorObj *err);

    MSError();
    MSError(errorObj *err);
    inline errorObj *get() { return this_; }

  private:
    ~MSError();
    errorObj *this_;
};

#endif
```

ms_error.cpp

```
#include "ms_error.hpp"

Persistent<FunctionTemplate> MSError::constructor;

void MSError::Initialize(Handle<Object> target) {
  HandleScope scope;

  constructor = Persistent<FunctionTemplate>::New(FunctionTemplate::New(MSError::New));
  constructor->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(1);
  constructor->SetClassName(String::NewSymbol("MSError"));

  // constructor->InstanceTemplate()->SetNamedPropertyHandler(MSError::NamedPropertyGetter, NULL, MSError::NamedPropertyQuery, NULL, MSError::NamedPropertyEnumerator);

  target->Set(String::NewSymbol("MSError"), constructor->GetFunction());
}

MSError::MSError(errorObj *err) : ObjectWrap(), this_(err) { }

MSError::MSError() : ObjectWrap(), this_(0) { }

MSError::~MSError() { }

Handle<Value> MSError::New(const Arguments& args)
{
  HandleScope scope;

  if (!args.IsConstructCall())
    return ThrowException(String::New("Cannot call constructor as function, you need to use 'new' keyword"));

  if (args[0]->IsExternal()) {
    Local<External> ext = Local<External>::Cast(args[0]);
    void *ptr = ext->Value();
    MSError *f =  static_cast<MSError *>(ptr);
    f->Wrap(args.This());
    return args.This();
  }

  return args.This();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is that the code above is fine.  The actual error was that the MSError::constructor was not initialized because I neglected to call it from the main module code.  The actual null object was MSError::constructor->GetFunction().

Thanks to Ben Noordhuis for pointing us in the right direction.